# Windows 7 - Login/Logoff so slow

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

I´m using Windows 7 64 bit in an environment with AD, GP and local profil.
I changed my profile to local.

Everytime when I power on my system (After entering username and password) or select shutdown it takes a few minutes to complete the task (5 to 10 minutes). There is only the standard Windows blue/white page with the working ring for a few minutes.
I think there is a problem with GP or something else.

How is it possible to see what my system is doing?
Is there a good analyzing tool?

Comment: Check eventlog, gpresult /r and if there is cleaning the swap space enabled.

Comment: Did the delay occur immediately after changing the profile to local?

Comment: The problem was also when the profil was stored in the network.

Answer (score 3):

You could turn Group Policy off, to determine if this is causing the delay.

- Navigate to HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\gpsrv.
- Double click the Start DWORD, and change the value to 4 – this disables the service.

Answer (score 1):

Try [**Soluto**](http://www.soluto.com/).

I believe it runs first, or before most other services or programs.

It records how long each process takes to complete, and what is causing the biggest delays.

Answer (score 1):

You may find some useful tools in the [Windows SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8279).

Explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/345006/how-can-i-identify-the-culprit-of-my-slow-windows-shutdown/347191#347191) are shutdown procedures, but there are similar tools for startup.