# Culprit of my slow system?

Tags: windows-7, performance

Of late, My laptop has been extremely slow. I tried debugging the reason. Using this, [How can I identify the culprit of my slow Windows shutdown?](https://superuser.com/questions/345006/how-can-i-identify-the-culprit-of-my-slow-windows-shutdown/347191#347191). I did found that idle process is taking 70% of the CPU Time

The screenshots are as follows:

Usage:
[image]

Usage Summary:
[image]

CPU Idle State:
[image]

Comment: Adding 3rd picture regarding CPU Idle state: http://picpaste.com/fig2-Li1MoJxe.png

Comment: Idle process should be taking 100% of your time (well, 99%)!

Comment: First: what is your taskmanager say is taking all those CPU-cycles? Second: Try disabling your virusscanner (mcshield.exe) to test if it's that one.

Comment: The idle process isn't taking any of your time. Your computer is probably waiting on something. Like, "stop Service X" but Service X needs to phone home to say "I'm stopping" before it stops and "home" is some dodgy server that's not always responding or fast. For a similar concept: http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2012/07/02/3506849.aspx

Comment: Can you provide a spec of the system, how old is the system, and is it always slow or only slow at times? As it stands, this question is very broad.

Comment: It is a thinkpad and it is pretty new (1 month old). It runs core i5-3320M, 8GB RAM and 256GB SSD. It is not always slow but at times yes, extremely slow. I'm just wondering where to start debugging. Taskmanager seems to be pretty clean.

Comment: Have you tried disabling your virusscanner (mcshield.exe) to test if it's that one?

Comment: Yes, I did. Just that I'm not able to replicate the scenario. Will update once I'm able to do it.

Comment: what is slow? When it the laptop slow?

Comment: Using taskmgr, display the processes.  Click on View > Select Columns and display the CPU column.  Click on the CPU column to   sort by usage.  What processes show as consuming a lot of CPU?  Also, is it only shutdown that is slow?