# How to determine which program is causing Window to have trouble logging off or shutting down?

Tags: windows-7, process, shutdown, logoff

When logging off Windows 7 SP1 or turning off the computer, how does one **quickly** diagnose which program is causing the system to issue a warning that a process needs to close?

[This post](https://superuser.com/questions/345006/how-can-i-identify-the-culprit-of-my-slow-windows-shutdown), does a great job providing an answer (albeit not a quick one!) for when the problem is completely unknown.  My case is different in that I am 99% certain it is a single program, but I want to make sure before I mess with things (disabling it is not trivial).

The 'Waiting for a program to close' dialog does not list any programs.

Lengthy bootups are pretty simply to diagnose, but how can one **quickly** determine which program is having trouble terminating itself during logoff or shutdown?

Comment: Doesn't the dialog say so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I identify the culprit of my slow Windows shutdown?](http://superuser.com/questions/345006/how-can-i-identify-the-culprit-of-my-slow-windows-shutdown)

Comment: @Arjan Thanks for finding that one.  I've edited my question to distinguish it from the other.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is when your on your PC do the key combo cntrl+alt+Del and windows will give you a couple options click start task manager then view what's running if there is nothing it most likely means a program is doing g some updating or things like that.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll see if it's possible.  It's definitely not an update, as it happens every time.  And it's only about 3-5 seconds, so it may be impossible to use task manager before it shuts itself down.