# Using Windows Performance Analyzer to identify slow windows 10 shutdown

Tags: windows-10, performance, shutdown

My windows 10 laptop is taking around 1 - 2 minutes to shutdown or sleep. I have followed the steps given on this question:

[How can I identify the culprit of my slow Windows shutdown?](https://superuser.com/questions/345006/how-can-i-identify-the-culprit-of-my-slow-windows-shutdown)

I used the Windows Performance Analyzer and generated an output `shutdown_BASE+DIAG+LATENCY_1.etl`

The graph looks like this:

[image]

I am not an expert of this kind of graph and there are so many graphs to look at, but from what I understand the graph shows that it takes around 11 seconds to shutdown, while in reality, it takes more than one minute for shutdown or sleep.

Can somebody guide me on reading the graph to identify the main problem of my slow shutdown?

**System information**

Windows 10 Pro, i7-2630QM, 12GB RAM, more than 500 GB free space.
Programs used: VirtualBox, Cisco VPN Client, Avast Free.

**EDIT**
This is the content of my `FullBoot.Shutdown.wpaprofile`
[image]

The `services.exe`takes around five secs, but it is still far lower than one minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WPA.exe, clock on Profiles->Apply->"Browse Catalog" and select `FullBoot.Shutdown.wpaprofile`.

Now you see this overview how long shutdown takes:

[image]

In this sample it takes 8s to shutdown. 2s are needed to close the user session (were 1.2s were spend to kill onedrive.exe) and shutting down the windows kernel/services takes 5s.

Look at your data to see where Windows spends most of the time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @magicandre1981. Please have a look at the edit.

Comment: @weha according to the data, Windows shuts down in 10s and the services.exe is the slowest part to stop. this is way longer compared to 1-2 minute that you wrote.

Comment: I don't know why WPA is only showing 11s. I still have an issue with my shutdown time, but nevertheless, this has answered my question regarding WPA. I will ask another question later. Thank you.