# App "G" preventing shutdown or restart

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, reboot

After updating my Windows 10 to creators update (build 15063.138) when I restart or shutdown the PC a screen appears and shows a 'G' app which is preventing the operation.

Is there a way to determine which application it is, or find out more details about it?

I do not see any "g" running process or installed application in my system.

[image]

Comment: Manually configure your system to start in a minimal boot configuration with AutoRuns and manually determine which entry is starting the application in question

Comment: Unless you think it may be an important process, there should be the option to force the shutdown. A process with just "g"as the name strikes me as a little sketchy though. I'd run a scan if I were you.

Comment: I think the problem is the utorrent. When I disabled the utorrent from the startup the problem disapered. The pc will shut down or reboot but I have to wait for it to close the program. It's annoyinga.

Comment: Are you using Geforce Experience? Because I am getting this too, and I am not using Utorrent, I don't know what is it..

Comment: I am experiencing this and am using both uTorrent and Geforce Experience. So my bet is that it is the Geforce Experience app, especially given that the app is called "G"

Comment: I am not using geforce experience. For me the problem is utorrent

Comment: Can you force the shutdown via cmd/powershell? (`shutdown.exe -s -f -t 00`)

Comment: I've been having the problem for several months, both on 17.05 and 17.11.  Using Process Explorer I fail to see any processes named "G" ca. fifteen minutes after a reboot. (I will check again tomorrow, and edit this comment if I find it then.)

When G is the only process stopping reboot and I tell Windows to quit anyway, it quite without apparent problems.

To the best of my knowledge I'm not running utorrent or Geforce.

Comment: I have seen this message too several times over the past few months. I do not have a GeForce chipset, nor Google Chrome, nor any Torrent software installed. The machine is very clean with no indication of malware. I could not find any `G.exe` on the drive.

Comment: it looks like Google Chrome backup feature, per reddit .. 
 https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/70xke5/app_called_g_is_preventing_shutdown_or_restart/

Answer (score 3):

Process Monitor will give you much more information about what is running and what those processes are doing.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

1. Begin the shutdown
2. Cancel once hung
3. Run Process Monitor and see what is going on.

Then enable verbose shutdown messages:

1. Run **gpedit.msc** from the Start menu search
2. Go to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System
3. In the right pane, double-click on **Verbose vs normal status messages**

You can also get detailed information about shutdown using the Windows SDK:

[Windows Performance Toolkit](https://superuser.com/a/347191/33758)

Answer (score 0):

Yes has a way to find the hide process and kill it.
But for that you will need a special tool called "**Process Explorer**" you can download it from [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).

I never hear a process called "G" , but sound like it's a **rundll32.exe** task , so find it on the process explorer and have a look in the tree of process running under the rundll32.

**PS**: If you don't find the process in the Process Explorer the chances of you have a malware/virus/worm is big. So my suggestion is to have your PC scanned with a good anti-virus.

Answer (score 0):

[See here](https://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-10-microsoft-unmasks-the-mysterious-g-app-stopping-you-shut-down/) for Microsoft's explanation:

> "We investigated and found an issue where windows related to GDI+ were
> only referenced as 'G'. We've fixed this, so going forward, these will
> now have the name 'GDI+ Window ()', where  will
> show the .exe name of the app using GDI+," the Windows Insider team
> said.