# Weird Slowness on My Win 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, sony-vaio

I have dual boot (Ubuntu and Win7) on my computer for 2 months. My computer is Sony VAIO VPCF22S1E. It has **i7 CPU** and **8GB RAM**

[image]

There is a weird slowness for a few months on Windows 7 OS. While using Ubuntu there isn't any slowness. But while i'm using Win 7 there is slowness.

Nod32 installed on my computer and i'm scanning my all devices on **in-depth scan** mode and there isn't any virus etc.

But on every Windows 7 startup i'm getting an "hKIow... (meanless chars) has stopped working" error. I have *googled* name of application (hKIow...) but there isn't any result.

Also i'm defragmenting my harddisk regularly  .

I **don't want to format** my computer.

How you any idea for me ?

Comment: It sounds like you are infected. The fact your computer is both slow and your getting an error means something is going on that isn't good.

Comment: I'm using NOD32 . Which antivirus / antimalware should i use ?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware  A good start at removing malware

Comment: It's not that NOD32 isn't working, it's that the virus may be capable of hiding itself in normal operation. All virus scanners are better border guards than internal police forces.

Answer (score 1):

Install Process monitor and enable boot logging, restart the PC and log into W7, then review the logs to see if you can nail down this random program, might be a leftover from malware removal.

[Source of Information](https://superuser.com/questions/261481/services-exe-batters-disk-writes-on-startup/334111#334111)